# ContentType: multipart/form-data when POSTing access_token to a resource

Tags: php, forms, oauth

I need Your help, i am implementing OAuth2 Services getting library from `https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php`

Every thing is woking fine but when i used `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form getting error `The access token provided is invalid`

My Form

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="contact" id="conact">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Image</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="image" id="image" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="25" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="status" id="status" maxlength="25" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Access Token</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="access_token" id="access_token" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

But When i remove it `enctype="multipart/form-data"` everthing is working file but image is not upload.

My contact.php have

```
if (!$server->verifyResourceRequest(OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())) {
        $response[]=$server->getResponse()->send();
        die;
}
 This Code is Checking Valid and Invalid Access Token
```

Please Help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not get these answer yet so i use the alternative method for this I passed the access token in action Like this

```
<form action="contact.php?access_token=" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="contact" id="conact">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Image</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="image" id="image" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="25" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="status" id="status" maxlength="25" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

It working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the similar problem solved by doing this

```html
<form action="contact.php?access_token=MY_TOKEN_HERE" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="contact" id="conact">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Image</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="image" id="image" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="25" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="status" id="status" maxlength="25" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

You can also check this issue on bsaffers library [issue](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/issues/155)
This is also mentioned on [oauth library](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.2)

Comment: Also I found mentions about this on oauth official library, enough for information [link](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-2.2)